# Changing the name of an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while. Basically i have an array called favourites. I want to map through it which is done in another component. I am passing multiple arrays to this component and all of have a name of data (they are coming from an API). So i want to change the name of the favourites anime to data so that i can pass it to the map component. I have attached pictures of my console log to make it a bit clearer. Thanks.

Current code

```
const {favourites} = useContext(FavouriteAnimeContext)
  const [favouriteAnimeArray] = [{favourites}]
  console.log(favouriteAnimeArray)
```

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1snAF.png)
[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxat4.png)

Comment: `const [favouriteAnimeArray] = [{ data: favourites }]`?

Comment: The question title is misleading and confusing. You cannot change name of an array, but you can copy it or reference it. I believe this is what you mean. In that case, take a look at Javascripts Objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Regardless of destructuring assignment this is basic [object property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). `const favouriteAnimeArray = {data: useContext(FavouriteAnimeContext).favourites};`. Destructuring and then creating a new array with an object in it just to destructure again is extremely opaque. (`const [favouriteAnimeArray] = [{favourites}];` is just adding work to `const favouriteAnimeArray = {favourites};`)

Answer (score 0):

```
const {favourites: data} = useContext(FavouriteAnimeContext); console.log({data});
```

You can use object destructuring with assigment to new variable name: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring

Comment: The OP seems to want the `favourites` array assigned to a property `data` in a new object, not aliased to `data`